# How to find initial feasible point for the dual problem of SVMs (Support Vector Machines)?

Tags: r, classification, svm, optimization, binary-data

## Problem

Is there a systematic way of finding an initial feasible point for the dual problem of an SVM?

## Context

I'm writing an implementation of Support Vector Machines for Binary Classification in R. I've coded everything I need for an SVM, I have the objective function as a function of a vector $\lambda$ which outputs

$$
\frac{\widetilde{\lambda}^\top K \widetilde{\lambda}}{4} - \langle \lambda, 1\rangle
$$
where $\widetilde{\lambda}:= (y_1\lambda_1, \ldots, y_n \lambda_n)^\top$ is the element-wise multiplication between the vector of labels $y=(y_1, \ldots, y_n)^\top$ and the input vector $\lambda$. I've also taken the constraints
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n y_i\lambda_i = 0\qquad \text{and}\qquad 0\leq \lambda_i\leq 1
$$
and re-written them into the form
$$
U\lambda -c\geq 0
$$
where
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & 1 & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots &\ddots\\
0 & 0 & \cdots & 1 \\
-1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & -1 & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots &\ddots &\vdots\\
0 & 0 & \cdots& -1 \\
y_1 & y_2 & \cdots & y_n \\
-y_1 & -y_2 & \cdots & -y_n
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda_1 \\
\lambda_2 \\ 
\vdots\\
\lambda_n
\end{pmatrix} -
\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
0 \\
\vdots \\
0
\end{pmatrix} \geq 0
$$
So that I can finally use the [function](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/constrOptim.html) `constrOptim()` by providing constrains and objective function. The only thing left is to find an initial feasible point. I tried a vector of all zeros, a vector of all ones. Then I created a function sampling random numbers from random intervals in order to generate random points, which I then test for feasibility. Yet, this function never terminates.

Is there a simple way to find one? Maybe from the primal?